# Rails: Conditionally bypass fragment caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, caching, memcached, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there any way to make fragment caching conditional, e.g. this will always cache:

```
 <% cache :calculation do %>
   <%= calc(x) %>
 <% end %>
```

But how could I make it cache if e.g. `x > 5`, something like:

```
 <% cache :calculation, { if: (x > 5) } do %>
   <%= calc(x) %>
 <% end %>
```

Of course, it could be done with an if-then statement and extracting out the cached content function, but that's messy. Possibly it could work by setting ttl to zero on this condition, but I suspect that would still put the item in the cache, which is wasted space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [cache_if](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper/cache_if)

```
<% cache_if((x > 5), :calculation) do %>
  <%= calc(x) %>
<% end %>
```